# How to Get WordPress custom post data in WooCommerce product meta panel?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, plugin-development, customization, woocommerce-offtopic

I have created one custom post in WordPress and also created one custom panel in Woocommerce product attribute panel.

Now, How I can display all the content of WordPress custom post into the Woocommerce product attribute list?

**Step 1:** I have created custom post in wordpress.

[image]

**Step 2:** I want data of WordPress custom post in Woocommerce Product Attribute.

[image: Woocommerce Product Attribute]

**Step 3:** Want to get all the data in WooCommerce Product Attribute with Checkbox Options.

Can anybody help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

My answer use 3 steps too :

**Step 1** : adding a new tab on the list

```
add_filter("woocommerce_product_data_tabs", function ($product_data_tabs) {

    $product_data_tabs["newTabId"] = [
        "label" => "Hello 1",
        "target" => "htmlIdOfTheBox",
        "class" => [],
    ];

    return $product_data_tabs;

});
```

**Step 2** : preparing the html box for this new tab

```
add_action("woocommerce_product_data_panels", function () {

    ?>

        <div id="htmlIdOfTheBox" class="panel woocommerce_options_panel">
            <strong>Hello 2</strong>
        </div>

    <?php

});
```

**Step 3** : filling this new box with the custom post types and saving the choices in the product. Sorry this big step is your work ;-)

I think that this step starts with getting all the custom post "album" with the "get_posts" function : http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_posts

Comment: Actually, you are not understand my question properly. I just want to solution of step 3. Request you to please read the question first, then after read the step again. I just want to help in step 3 to get the data of custom post in custom tab of product attribute.

Comment: I don't have understand because we are not here to give the solution but only to help to improve your code. And there is no code in your question so if you want more help, show us what you have tried et explain what you wish to have with this code. --- I edit the 3rd step of my answer to try to add some help

Comment: Yup.. its good.. it is actually that I want.. Thanxx

Comment: @dvs.spy If the answer worked for you, the best thank you is to accept it (click the check mark under the vote arrows on the left), and once you have enough reputation, you can also vote up answers that are helpful.

Comment: Hey Gabriel.. Answer is not fully worked for me but the instruction to use get_posts is hint that useful to me.. if I mark the right, other users would be misguided and think that how it worked.. so i have not marked the answer..  only for the getting reputation, i never do like this with other.. thanks..